# function in coffeescript on cheerio object not running

Tags: function, coffeescript, cheerio

I have this code:

```
 $ = $root.cheerio.load(body)
 results = $('#selector').map (index, element)->
      items = []
      $(this).find('.item_link').each (i, el)->
        console.log("asdf")
        items[i] =  $(this).attr('title')

      result=
        name: $(this).find('.the_name_link').attr('title') 
        #HERE I'd like to do something with items but it's not working
      return result

    return callback(null,results)
```

So when this code is executed, there's basically no error, and in my interface I get a result with

```
[
    {
        "name": "The Name I was looking for"
        }
]
```

But it seems the code in the each block never gets executed (there's no console output 'asdf'). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: doing the similar call with jquery on the same page in the browser works. There are multiple elements in .item_link

Comment: Can you post the HTML of `body` please? Have you explored the possibility that `$(this).find('.item_link')` is simply not matching anything and returning an empty array?

Comment: It is in fact. I wonder why. Because if I do that in the console in the browser it doesn't! I am a bit baffled...

Comment: Seems to be a bug in cheerio? Dumping the whole html of the element just misses a lot of that html element! weird...

Comment: Again, if you post the HTML, we can provide specific help. I think it is unlikely that cheerio is going to drop elements/attributes of the parsed HTML just by a parse->rerender cycle. Your code is read-only anyway so there's no chance you are accidentally altering the DOM. But anyway continue the debugging process of isolating the weirdness to smaller and smaller sections of code/markup until you figure it out.

Comment: (blush) (blush) (re-blush) although tricky to find, the problem lay somewhere else. The code was submitting incorrect non-fatal parameters to the server app, so no error visible. This resulted in only a portion of html being returned... while when accessing through the browser, visibly the correct parameters were sent - displaying the complete html... :) thanks for supporting! Maybe I should close this one as in fact it is a no-issue really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now this has been seriously ill-leading. Problem was a wrong parameter sent to the app which would reply with incomplete html, thus the code was (correctly...) not finding the divs I was looking for :)

Thus the coffeescript above is correct.